# django url include with multiple urls doesn't work

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, url, routes

so I have this code:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
]
```

myapp.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^what/', views.do_something),
]
```

going to myapp/ works but going to myapp/what doesn't work and ends up returning 404 page not found...

what did I do wrong?

Comment: You missed the trailing slash - /myapp/what/

Comment: Can you show the error message, specifically the patterns that were tried?